# PHP Regex Replace digits after first two any characters

Tags: php, preg-replace

I need help in fixing a string, i need to remove DIGITS from a string using "preg_replace" after the first two any characters of the string, examples can be:

1. N02  [ Should remove 2 ]
2. AX1001 [ Should remove 1001 ]
3. AR2003 [ Should remove 2003 ]
4. AR [ out put should be AR, because there are no digits ]

Currently am using:
preg_replace( '/\d/', '', "A0123" );

But it removes digits from the start. Any one can help?

UPDATE:
AXZ1001 : in this case it should product AXZ
AX1001 : in this case it should product AX
A1001 : in this case it should product A1

Comment: What about `ABC123XYZ999`, should it end up as `ABCXYZ` or `ABCXYZ999`?

Comment: If you just want to keep the first 2 characters of a string why don't you just use `substr()`? If this is not what you want to do, what you want to happen if a string has both digits and other characters after the first 2 characters?

Comment: i dont want to use substr coz i need to remove digits after first two characters, but if after first two characters there is no digit, i don't wanna remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `\K` feature:

```
$str = preg_replace('~\A.{2,}?\K[0-9]+~', '', $str);
```

Where `\K` removes all on the left from match result.

Since `.{2,}?` is a lazy quantifier, the fewest characters (but at least 2) are matched until a digit is found. It can be replaced by a greedy version with: `..[^0-9]*`

If you want to deal with this kind of string: `ABC123XYZ999` to obtain `ABCXYZ`:

```
$str = preg_replace('~(?:\A..|(?!\A)\G)[^0-9]*\K[0-9]+~', '', $str);
```

`\G` is an anchor for the end of the last match.

Comment: preg_replace('~\A..\K[0-9]+~', '', "AX1001" );
This worked, but where it tells that ignore first two characters?

Comment: Ok, I will adapt the two first patterns to deal with this case.

Comment: AXZ1001 : in this case it should product AXZ
AX1001 : in this case it should product AX
A1001 : in this case it should product A1

Comment: It worked, can you explain what is happening in the expressions?
'~\A.{2,}?\K[0-9]+~'